# SIGUSR1 signal isn't refreshing immediately

Tags: linux, bash, signals

How can I force SIGUSR1 signal to execute immediately? At the moment it waits for some interval, which is not good in my case (it needs to be executed immediately)

```
usr(){
    echo "some msg"
}

trap usr SIGUSR1
```

Comment: When does it wait? When the shell is sleeping or otherwise inactive? Do you have a minimal case that shows the delay you are talking about?

Comment: Between commands. Let's say there is a command sleep(5), and if I try to use this signal, it will wait until the next command.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap#When_is_the_signal_handled.3F

Comment: hmm the problem is this only works on sleeps?

Comment: That works for any command you need to be able to interrupt (assuming you can run them in the background).

Comment: Hmm had some strange errors for others, so I just made an if statement that checks if the command is sleep. Thank you! :)

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: The problem is actually still there. It's a school assignment and I'm using their tests so i actually dont know whats wrong.

Comment: You are going to have to explain more clearly exactly what you are doing exactly what you are seeing and exactly what is failing if you want more help.

Comment: alright, what we have to do is a command runner. Script gets an argument, which is a text file which contains a main command (first column) and commands who will communicate with the main commnand via substitution. We have to do bunch of other things, but I managed to do everything but these signals. So example of a line looks like this: wc -l <(tree /). Then we have to run those commands, nothing special-"eval". Then there is the problem when I try to handle signals. The script isn't reacting to signals immediately, but it gets multiple signals and then reacts to it.